# Performance improvement for linq query with distinct

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Considering the sample table

```
Col 1, Col2, Col3
1    , x   , G
1    , y   , H
2    , z   , J
2    , a   , K
2    , a   , K
3    , b   , E
```

I want below result, i.e distinct rows

```
1    , x   , G
1    , y   , H
2    , z   , J
2    , a   , K
3    , b   , E
```

I tried

```
var Result = Context.Table.Select(C => 
                 new { 
                       Col1 = C.Col1,
                       Col2 = C.Col2,
                       Col3 = C.Col3 
                      }).Distinct();
```

and

```
Context.Table.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Col1,x.Col2,x.Col3}).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
```

The results are as expected, however my table has 35 columns and 1 million records and its size will keep on growing, the current time for the query is 22-30 secs, so how to improve the performance and get it down to 2-3 secs?

Comment: Maybe have a HashSet of a custom struct type which implements IEquatable. Compare the properties which have the most variation first in the IEquatable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `distinct` is the way to go... I'd say that the first approach you tried is the correct one - but do you really need all 1 million rows? See what `where` conditions you can add or maybe take just the first x records?

```
var Result = Context.Table.Select(c => new 
    { 
        Col1 = c.Col1,
        Col2 = c.Col2,
        Col3 = c.Col3 
    })
    .Where(c => /*some condition to narrow results*/)
    .Take(1000) //some number of the wanted amount of records
    .Distinct();
```

What you might be able to do, is to use the `rownum` to select in bulks. Something like:

```
public <return type> RetrieveBulk(int fromRow, int toRow)
{
    return Context.Table.Where(record => record.Rownum >= fromRow && record.Rownum < toRow)
        .Select(c => new 
        { 
            Col1 = c.Col1,
            Col2 = c.Col2,
            Col3 = c.Col3 
        }).Distinct();
}
```

This code you can then do something like:

```
List<Task<return type>> selectTasks = new List<Task<return type>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i+=1000)
{
    selectTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RetrieveBulk(i, i + 1000)));
}

Task.WaitAll(selectTasks);

//And then intercet data using some efficient structure as a HashSet so when you intersect it wont be o(n)2 but o(n)
```

Comment: I don't have a where clause so I have to deal with all the records at one go, or is there a way I can get distinct values for each column in a table? without multiple queries?

Comment: the `distinct` operation is an expensive operation to do because it has to go through all the data and check...